# If/Then apply different function depending on each value in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an allegedly easy to solve question, but i still cannot figure it out:

I have an array with 1000 numbers called "mu" like this:

```
array([2.25492522e-01, 2.21059993e-01, 2.16757006e-01,....)
```

Now i need to plug these values in two different functions:
For numbers in the array, that are less than 0.009, i need to use equation1:

```
nu = 1 - 5.5 * mu**(0.66) + 3.77 * mu
```

For all other numbers in the array, i need to plug these into equation2:

```
nu = 0.819**(-11.5*mu)+0.0975**(-70.1*mu)
```

In the end, i need an array of the function values "nu".

I gave this code a try, but it didn't work

```
for item in mu:
    if item < 0.009:
       nu = 1 - 5.5 * mu**(0.66) + 3.77 * mu
    else:
       nu = 0.819**(-11.5*mu)+0.0975**(-70.1*mu)

print nu
```

How can I tell Python to put the right numbers in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is you aren't using `item` in your `for` loop. Nor are you appending to a list or assigning to a new array to store your results. In any case, NumPy has specific functions designed for this task. For example, using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def func1(x):
    return 1 - 5.5 * x**(0.66) + 3.77 * x

def func2(x):
    return 0.819**(-11.5*x)+0.0975**(-70.1*x)

res = np.where(mu < 0.009, func1(mu), func2(mu))
```

While you may feel this is inefficient as twice as many calculations are being processed than required, this is far outweighted by the benefits of vectorised operations.

Comment: Thank you, jpp. Your provided answer works as expected!